# Echo values from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have decoded the JSON but i am not able to echo the single values.
I want to print "ref" from "transaction" array.

```
array(3) { ["method"]=> string(5) "check" ["trace"]=> string(19) "4000/22390/5f67437b" ["order"]=> array(11) { ["ref"]=> string(64) "E35B2D1E4F7A28B9F7D397B22FFB84B75EFB3DB091B91540CA0B759924EA378E" ["cartid"]=> string(19) "18460_5f67381dec52e" ["test"]=> int(1) ["amount"]=> string(6) "545.00" ["currency"]=> string(3) "AED" ["description"]=> string(22) "Your order from Baaqah" ["status"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(3) ["text"]=> string(4) "Paid" } ["transaction"]=> array(7) { ["ref"]=> string(12) "030025829659" ["date"]=> string(21) "20 Sep 2020 15:08 GST" ["type"]=> string(4) "sale" ["class"]=> string(4) "ECom" ["status"]=> string(1) "A" ["code"]=> string(6) "909959" ["message"]=> string(10) "Authorised" }
```

I used the below commands but i cannot print the last one. It's coming out empty.

```
  var_dump($response);
  echo "METHOD: ". $response["method"]; // Access Array data
  echo "TRACE: ". $response["trace"]; // Access Array data
  echo "REF: ". $response["transaction"]["ref"]; // Access Array data
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you format your dump, you will see that its in: `$response["order"]["transaction"]["ref"]`

```
array(3) { 
["method"]=> string(5) "check" 
["trace"]=> string(19) "4000/22390/5f67437b" 
["order"]=> array(11) { 
  ["ref"]=> string(64) "E35B2D1E4F7A28B9F7D397B22FFB84B75EFB3DB091B91540CA0B759924EA378E" 
  ["cartid"]=> string(19) "18460_5f67381dec52e"
  ["test"]=> int(1) 
  ["amount"]=> string(6) "545.00" 
  ["currency"]=> string(3) "AED"
  ["description"]=> string(22) "Your order from Baaqah"
  ["status"]=> array(2) { 
    ["code"]=> int(3)
    ["text"]=> string(4) "Paid"
  } 
  ["transaction"]=> array(7) { 
     ["ref"]=> string(12) "030025829659" 
     ["date"]=> string(21) "20 Sep 2020 15:08 GST" 
     ["type"]=> string(4) "sale" 
     ["class"]=> string(4) "ECom" 
     ["status"]=> string(1) "A" 
     ["code"]=> string(6) "909959" 
     ["message"]=> string(10) "Authorised" 
   }
}
```